# Getting values from a JSON object Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

`{
   "questions_id":[
      "7",
      "9",
      "2"
   ],
   "select_param_type":[
      "is greater than",
      "is less than",
      "is less than"
   ],
   "select_param_value":[
      "2",
      "4",
      "2"
   ],
   "radio_type":[
      "and",
      "or",
   ]
}`

I would like to consume this JSON in the order: `questions_id, select_param_type, select_param_value, radio_type`.

Something like `["7", "is greater than", "2", "and", "9", "is less than", "4", "or", "2", "is less than",  "2" ]`

The `radio_type` is the joining key from one Array level to the next.

How can I achieve this?

Thanks.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck, exactly? We'll _help_ you, but this isn't a free write-all-my-code or do-all-my-thinking service. Please edit your question to show us any progress you have made in implementing your requirement. Hint: a `for` loop would make this fairly easy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could take an array of keys and an index and get the value mapped by index. At the end pop the last undefined value.

```js
var data = { questions_id: ["7", "9", "2"], select_param_type: ["is greater than", "is less than", "is less than"], select_param_value: ["2", "4", "2"], radio_type: ["and", "or"] },
    order = ['questions_id', 'select_param_type', 'select_param_value', 'radio_type'],
    result = [],
    i = 0;

do result.push(...order.map(k => data[k][i]));
while (data.radio_type[i++])

result.pop();

console.log(result.join(' '));
console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Thank you...This is what I was looking for

Comment: Is it possible to remove occurrences of the comma?

Comment: do you want a joined string?

Answer (score 0):

Here you go with a solution

```js
var json = {
   "questions_id":[
      "7",
      "9",
      "2"
   ],
   "select_param_type":[
      "is greater than",
      "is less than",
      "is less than"
   ],
   "select_param_value":[
      "2",
      "4",
      "2"
   ],
   "radio_type":[
      "and",
      "or",
   ]
};

var orderingKey = ["questions_id", "select_param_type", "select_param_value", "radio_type"];

var result = [];

orderingKey.map(key => {
  result.push(...json[key]);
});

console.log(result);
```

Loop through the orderingKey array to get the keys and the using spread operator spread the values of the key.

Comment: No. The result should be` ["7", "is greater than", "2", "and", "9", "is less than", "4", "or", "2", "is less than",  "2" ]`

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
const datas = {
    "questions_id":[
        "7",
        "9",
        "2"
    ],
    "select_param_type":[
        "is greater than",
        "is less than",
        "is less than"
    ],
    "select_param_value":[
        "2",
        "4",
        "2"
    ],
    "radio_type":[
        "and",
        "or",
    ]
}

const keys = ["questions_id", "select_param_type", "select_param_value", "radio_type"];

let result = [];

keys.map((key, index) => {
    for(let item in datas) {
        if (datas[item][index]) {
            result.push(datas[item][index])
        }
    }
});

console.log(result);
```

The result is

```
["7", "is greater than", "2", "and", "9", "is less than", "4", "or", "2", "is less than", "2" ]
```